# Split string between characters with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split the string:

```
> s = Ladegårdsvej 8B7100 Vejle
```

with a regex into:

```
[street,zip,city] = ["Ladegårdsvej 8B", "7100", "Vejle"]
```

`s` varies a lot, the only certain part is that there are always 4 digits in the zip and a whitespace afterwards. My idea is thus to "match from the right" on 4 digits and a whitespace to indicate that the string should be split at that point in the string.

Currently I'm able to get `street` and `city` like this:

```
> print re.split(re.compile(r"[0-9]{4}\s"), s)
["Ladegårdsvej 8B", "Vejle"]
```

How would I go about splitting `s` as desired; in particular, how to do it in the middle of the string between the number in `street` and `zip`?

Comment: Would all strings have the same overall format as that string, cause then you could just split it on whitespace cause that seems to be a delimiter between the three

Comment: @Professor_Joykill: There is no whitespace between street & zip.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill please note that OP wants to put `7100` rather than `8B7100` into `zip`.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/dmyo6b, you may match and *capture* the parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `re.split`, but make the four digits a capturing group:

```
>>> s = "Ladegårdsvej 8B7100 Vejle"
>>> re.split(r"(\d{4}) ", s)
['Ladegårdsvej 8B', '7100', 'Vejle']
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) (emphasis mine)

> Split string by the occurrences of pattern. **If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.** If maxsplit is nonzero, at most maxsplit splits occur, and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have street, getting zip is trivial:

```
zip = s[len(street):len(street)+4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
st="Ladegårdsvej 8B7100 Vejle"
reg=r'([0-9]{4})'
rep=re.split(reg,st)
print rep
```

Solution for other test cases as provided by [RasmusP_963](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2454932/rasmusp-963) sir.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
st="Birkevej 8371900 Roskilde"
print re.split(r"([0-9]{4}) ",st)
```

Comment: That won't work, because there could be a `street` address with long house number without letters (e.g. `Birkevej 8371900 Roskilde`), so I need to include the whitespace afterwards to ensure it matches on the last four numbers (the `zip`).